# Cant connect to mysql server when port is change c#

Tags: c#, mysql, port

Im using xammp as my platform for my database

Usually the defualt port of mysql is 3306 and it is working properly

But when I change the port like 4444 in my.ini I have an error message receive

> cannot connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

By using this connection string

```
string connectString = "datasource=xxx.xx.xx.xxx;port=4444;username=root;password="";database=XXXXX;";
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with port `3306`? Did you open port `4444` for mysql on the database server?

Comment: I just want to change the port becuase previously my db was hack, I want to reconfigure the port and change it to other number, yeah and it starts succesfully

Comment: You need to open the port for incoming connections in firewall.

Comment: I just add inbound and outbound rule for the port

Answer (score 0):

Well XAMPP might require a restart of MySQL server in order to update open port. But according to [Connector strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/), parameter "Port" might be ignored if Unix socket is used. So you can also check that.

Also, I know [that have PHP in title](https://phpmysqllearners.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/changing-phpxampp-port-number-in-xampp/), but I think it might be connected with your problem. Try this and say if it helped